# mpdf - set headers and footers

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

How to set headers and footer in PDF documents generated with mpdf?

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div>Page: {PAGENO}</div>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div>test</div>');
$mpdf->Output('test.pdf');
```

This writes `test` to the document but no header?

How can I add the total page number to the header like `Page 1 of 3`

Comment: Have you tried all from the manual page? https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-footers.html

Comment: yes.. have tried both methods

Comment: Your code works for me in mPDF 7.0.1 and writes the header `Page: 1`. Add details of your environment if experiencing trouble.

Comment: You can print total number of pages using `{nb}` placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

I use Mpdf version 8.1.6 and this code works for me:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div>Page: {PAGENO}</div>');
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div>Some Footer</div>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div>test</div>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

And total pages work only when they are included in the header or footer part.
For example, you can write like this:

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div>Page {PAGENO} of {nbpg}</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**This method worked for me**

Headers and Footers

If you want to have headers and footers that appear on every page, **add them to your  tag** like this:

Header

```
<htmlpageheader name="page-header">
    Your Header Content
</htmlpageheader>
```

Footer

```
<htmlpagefooter name="page-footer">
    Your Footer Content
</htmlpagefooter>
```

Now you just need to define them with the **name attribute in your CSS**:

```
@page {
  header: page-header;
  footer: page-footer;
}
```

Inside of headers and footers {PAGENO} can be used to display the page number.

Reference [form here](https://github.com/mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf#headers-and-footers)